# Fectch this array using http package in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, api, dart

I wanted to display the images inside contained in the arrays of this api. Can someone help to this? thank u!

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a model at first, i suggest to use [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), it generate model based on your json api.
2. now you need to add http package to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  http: <latest_version>
```

3. now time to implement connection:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
.
.
.
Future<ImgModel> fetchImgUrl() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse(your url here));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    return ImgModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // throw exception if not 200
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

now you can get your image url from json,
you can implement `setState` in your connection and pass it to an instance to get all result in list or change it into `Future<List<ImgModel>>` to get list of urls! playaround to get best result

4. and finally if you need to show your image you can do by `Image.network`, if you have list of image you can use `ListView.builder`

```
return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: yourList.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
               return Image.network(yourList[index].imageUrl);
           },
       );
```

i hope it was clear!

resources:

- https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flutter/flutter_accessing_rest_api.htm
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-apis-in-flutter-8745968103e9